# Add gradle resources unders custom output dir

Tags: java, gradle

I have a project structure like this (using gradle 2.11):

```
submodule1
|
- src
  |
  - main
    |
    - resources
      |
      - file1
submodule2
|
- resources
  |
  - file2
  - file3
```

I'm adding some additional things to `submodule1`'s `resources` via:

```
sourceSets {
   main {
      resources {
         srcDir("../submodule2/resources")
      }
   }
}
```

Is there an easy way to specify a custom output path for resources from `submodule2`? Currently when I jar it, all resource files `file1`, `file2` etc. will be put inside the jar on the top level. I would like the `submodule1` files to stay at top level and the `submodule2` resources to be put inside the jar under a custom path i.e. `submodule2resources`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter the files during the jar file is built. It's done in `jar` closure in `build.gradle` file using the [DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html). The problem here lies in the fact that when you add a source set and jar is prepared the information about the origin of a given file is lost - all files belong to submodule1 now - hence a workaround here is needed:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

project.ext.sm2Resources = project.file("../sm2/src/main/resources")

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir(sm2Resources)
        }
    }
}

jar {
  eachFile { f ->
      if(new File(sm2Resources, f.file.name).exists()) {
        f.path = "sm2/$f.name"
      }
  }
}
```

Check out the [demo](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/39160014).